# I am deploying a Rails app to Azure through Git and I get a no such file error when pushing

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, git, azure

I am pushing a Rails web app to Azure and while pushing I'm am getting a remote:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, 
stat '/home/site/repository/include/python2.7'
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment. 
remote: Kudu Sync failed
```

I tried adding the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` as a config variable but that deploys from a zip which I'm not sure I want to do and the app wasn't working with that.  I've read that I might need a symlink but not really sure thats the way to go.

Comment: It is  the most similar question I have found: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/17648

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete step by step guide to deploy rails app in Azure you can refer:

https://gist.github.com/JeremyC-za/edb758525d5d98870f009dc1bba54d15

You have to set an environment variable like so:

**`KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD=true`**

It changes the behavior of **`selectNodeVersion`** function run by **`deploy.sh`**

**`Note:`**
Rails apps are created with a **`package.json`** file  and Azure uses this file to determine what type of app you're trying to deploy. Flags the app as a node.js in default scenario web site, and generates a deployment script , because of this reason it gets failed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate the link but, it looks like Azure can't create symlinks when I deploy so I am getting an error.  Anybody know of a workaround.